# What permission is needed to create a new app in the Google Play Console?

Tags: android, google-play-console

When I try to create a new app in the Google Play Console it says that I need permission. I want to know what permission I need to ask the owner for. I've looked at the [available permissions](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9844686?hl=en) and it does not say anything about new apps.

Answer (score 7):

The user needs to either be the account owner, or have the admin permission